# Populate a radio button with values from SQLite Database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, radio-button, populate

I have been searching everywhere for solutions to this and to no avail.

Overall, I'm trying to populate radio buttons with data from my SQLite database.

I started by trying to store the data in a ListView but every time I do this, the ListView returns my package name with a number after it (is it the index of the database or an address?). What it returns looks like this "com.example.appname.ClassName@41ca0130" Any ideas how to solve this?

**Partial Database Code**

```
    public List<Plan> getAllPlans(String carrierName) 
    {
            List<Plan> planList = new ArrayList<Plan>();

            //String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM plans";
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + PLAN_CARRIER + " = '" + carrierName + "'";

            Log.e("PlansHelper", selectQuery);

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            if (c.moveToFirst()) 
            {
                    do 
                    {
                            Plan plan = new Plan();
                            plan.setID(c.getInt((c.getColumnIndex(PLAN_ID))));
                            plan.setCarrier((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PLAN_CARRIER))));
                            plan.setCarrier((c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(PLAN_NAME))));
                            planList.add(contact);
                    } 
            while (c.moveToNext());
    }

    return planList;
}
```

**Partial Activity Code**

```
    ListView listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);

    List<Plan> plan = new ArrayList<Plan>(); 
    plan=db.getAllPlans("Meteor");

    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, plan); 
    listContent.setAdapter(adapter);
```

If ye have any ideas, let me know and I'll try any suggestions. Also, if ye can point me in the right direction of how to accomplish the overall task of populating radio buttons with SQLite data; that'd be amazing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override toString() for Plan class.
Please refer Android Reference for ArrayAdapter.

[Android Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20java.util.List%3CT%3E%29)
***"Override the toString() method of your objects to determine what text will be displayed for the item in the list."***

Hope this helps!

Comment: I kind of got this part working but not too sure if it's "good programming".

I changed the class like this;

`public List<String> getAllPlans(String carrierName) {
List<String> planList = new ArrayList<String>();`

and return a string